# how can i get the CPU number of current task (In kernel)?

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there any way to get CPU number of current task?
(What I need is not the number of CPUs the task is running on, but which CPU the task is running on)

This process must be in kernel-level, therefore something like command line won't help.

I am trying to do this by calling kernel functions or using kernel data structures(like task_struct), but I am having trouble.

Comment: You might want to copy that answer into a new answer here (including the link to the source, of course).

Answer (score 2):

A rather old question but this might be helpful for the future:

If you have `CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK` enabled (which is usually the default) then you can simply access the current CPU of the task using the `cpu` member of `task_struct`: `current->cpu`

As you can find in the source:

```c
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /* Current CPU: */
    unsigned int            cpu;
#endif
```

And also the previous CPU of the task as could be found in `task_struct`:

```c
    /*
     * recent_used_cpu is initially set as the last CPU used by a task
     * that wakes affine another task. Waker/wakee relationships can
     * push tasks around a CPU where each wakeup moves to the next one.
     * Tracking a recently used CPU allows a quick search for a recently
     * used CPU that may be idle.
     */
    int             recent_used_cpu;
```

You may also use `cpu = task_cpu(p)` which return id of the CPU.

Each task is also associated with a `runqueue` of a CPU. and each `runqueue` has a `cpu` field. The `runqueue` could be simply retrieved by `rq = task_rq(p)` and then `rq->cpu`.

Answer (score 0):

The `sched_getcpu()` "determine CPU on which the calling thread is running" function appears to exist solely to provide this.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html

Comment: That's a user-space function, the OP was asking for a kernel-space function.

Answer (score -1):

CPU details of processes are in  `/proc/[pid]/stat`
39th field gives last CPU number where it was executed.

> (39) processor  %d  (since Linux 2.2.8)
>                           CPU number last executed on.

For more details: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html